# Warbler config.java_classes and log4j.properties

Tags: log4j, jruby, warbler

I'm packaging up a rails app with warbler and I want app specific logging.  I've added the log4j and commons-loggin jar to the WEB-INF/lib directory, and I want to add log4j.properties to the WEB-INF/classes directory.  The problem is, I also want environment specific logging, so my staging/production use different properties (ie. INFO instead of DEBUG) than my devel.  I can't just do a:

```
config.java_classes = FileList["lib/log4j-#{RAILS_ENV}.properties"]
```

because Tomcat seems to look for the specific file `log4j.properties`.  Is there any way to get warbler to rename this file to just `log4j.properties`?  Or is there a better mechanism for app specific, environment specific logging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And for the final answer.  RAILS_ENV doesn't seem to work in warbler, but looking through the [docs](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/classes/Warbler/Config.html) on warble config, there's a webxml attribute that contains rails.env, modifying my code to pull the file like:

```
config.java_classes = FileList["lib/properties/log4j.properties.#{config.webxml.rails.env}"]
```

Worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad that you were able to work out the answer for yourself! Do you get more points for answering your own questions?

Answer (score 0):

Guess I should just read further down in the warble file itself.  You can configure pathmaps for the java_classes.  Here's what I used:

```
config.java_classes = FileList["lib/properties/log4j.properties.#{RAILS_ENV}"]
config.pathmaps.java_classes << "%n"
```

The only problem I've found is that this doesn't actually put the log4j.properties in the WEB-INF/classes directory anymore.  It now puts it in the Root.  Seems odd that it specifically says in the docs:

> One or more pathmaps defining how the java classes should be copied into WEB-INF/classes

I wouldn't think I'd have to add in that WEB-INF/classes path manually but I did.  So finally then, this worked:

```
config.java_classes = FileList["lib/properties/log4j.properties.#{RAILS_ENV}"]
config.pathmaps.java_classes << "WEB-INF/classes/%n"
```

using the files log4j.properties.#{RAILS_ENV} in the lib/properties directory

Comment: scratch that.  It appears that Warbler is not getting the rails_env properly,  I'm using warbler (0.9.14).  In my cap deploy I set rails_env appropriately, not sure what's going on here, but it always gets log4j.properties.development